# DataTables AJAX is not calling server-side method

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, datatables

I am trying to implement [DataTables.Net Server side](https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) in ASP.NET web forms.

```
$('#GridViewClient').dataTable({                
    stateSave: true,
    Processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: "22.aspx/GetAllUsers"                
});


[WebMethod]    
public static string GetAllUsers()
{
    string sResult = "";

    try
    {
        BussinessLayer.Client obj = new BussinessLayer.Client();

        int nDraw = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["draw"]);
        List<Client_table> lst = obj.GetAllClient();

        ReturnData oResult = new ReturnData();
        oResult.draw = nDraw;
        oResult.recordsTotal = lst.Count;
        oResult.recordsFiltered = lst.Count;

        foreach (Client_table o in lst)
            oResult.data.Add(o.ToString());

        sResult = oResult.ToString();


    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        string sMsg = err.Message;
        sResult = "";
    }

    return sResult;
}
```

When I try to call this method using a normal ajax call, it is working fine and the debug point is also hitting. But when I call this method using a datatables ajax request, the method is not getting called?

Comment: need more details in javascript code, when is that jquery called ?

Comment: @MichaelB. Sorry i was actually busy on other projects. My jquery is called on document ready. Do you have any working examples on this ?